# iText: Do margins apply when using PdfContentByte?

Tags: itext

I created a new document with 36 points margin all around:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(1224f, 792f);
Document doc = new Document(rect, 36f, 36f, 36f, 36f);
```

I drew a rectangle at (0, 0) using PdfContentByte:

```
cb.rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
cb.fill();
```

The rectangle gets drawn at the lower-left hand corner of the page. It ignores the margins completely. Is this the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the expected result?

Yes, it is. The margins only are taken into account by operations adding content via the `Document`.

Whenever you access the content directly (`DirectContent`, `UnderContent`,`OverContent`), you can draw wherever you want.

When creating footers or headers, you actually rely on that behavior.

Furthermore, the margins have no influence on the coordinate system. As the coordinate system is configurable, one could have chosen 0,0 to be the lower left of the margin border. Actually you can do so by defining a page size rectangle that way. But that is not the normal usage of iText.